# Bug in scipy.special.ellipkinc - incomplete elliptic integral

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods

In using SciPy's `scipy.special.ellipeinc` and `ellipkinc`, there seem to be some islands of numerical instability. For example,

```
>>> from scipy.special import ellipkinc
>>> ellipkinc(0.9272952180016123, 0.68359375000000011)
nan
>>> ellipkinc(0.9272952180016123, 0.6835937500000002)
2.0518660200390668
>>> ellipkinc(0.9272952180016123, 0.68359375)
1.0259330100195332
>>> ellipkinc(0.9272952180016123, 0.68359374)
1.0259330081166262
```

This happens where k^2.sin^2(phi) is close to 0.3, but there is nothing unusual about the elliptic integrals themselves here, so presumably it's a numerical thing. I don't know enough about the inner workings of this algorithm to say what's wrong, so what's my best option? I thought of:
`round(0.68359375000000011,8)`
say, but this is surely going to slow my code?

Comment: I'd recommend changing the title of the question to make a bit more specific.

Comment: I created a bug report: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is more an extended comment about the problem than an answer to what to do about it.)

This looks like a bug in `ellipkinc`.  I get just one floating point value where the function returns `nan`, and four adjacent floating point values where the function returns twice the "correct" value:

```
In [91]: phi = 0.9272952180016123

In [92]: mbad = 0.68359375000000011

In [93]: m = np.nextafter(mbad, 0)

In [94]: mvals = []

In [95]: for j in range(10):
   ....:     mvals.append(m)
   ....:     m = np.nextafter(m, 1)
   ....:     

In [96]: mvals
Out[96]: 
[0.68359375,
 0.68359375000000011,
 0.68359375000000022,
 0.68359375000000033,
 0.68359375000000044,
 0.68359375000000056,
 0.68359375000000067,
 0.68359375000000078,
 0.68359375000000089,
 0.683593750000001]

In [97]: ellipkinc(phi, mvals)
Out[97]: 
array([ 1.02593301,         nan,  2.05186602,  2.05186602,  2.05186602,
        2.05186602,  1.02593301,  1.02593301,  1.02593301,  1.02593301])
```